# How to fix use dependancy error in docker?

Tags: python, docker

I found a base firefox standalone image, I am trying to run a script using selenium with geckodriver inside a docker container, I've tried to install requirements from the dockerfile but get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'`

This is my Dockerfile:

```
From selenium/node-firefox:3.141.59-iron

 # Set buffered environment variable
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

 # Set the working directory to /app
USER root
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80

 # Install packacges needed for crontab and selenium

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo libpulse0 pulseaudio software-properties-common libappindicator1 fonts-liberation python-pip virtualenv
RUN apt-get install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin cron nano -y

# RUN virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.6 venv36
# RUN . venv36/bin/activate

 # Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
ADD requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /app/

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

I am expecting my script to run, I'm not sure why there it is using Python2.7 in the interactive shell, I thought the selenium docker image came with 3.6 and selenium already installed

Comment: It comes with both, it's just `python3` has to be explicitly selected. This is default behavior on most *nix systems (including mac)

Comment: You are right I just had to specify it, I still haven't been able to use any of the python libraries like selenium though

Answer (score 1):

Your container comes with both `python` (python 2) and `python3`. It's just `python` defaults to the 2.7 instance. You can change this behavior by issuing:

```
RUN alias python=python3
```

in your `Dockerfile`